SqlAlchemy:How to access extra fields in association object in Left table using AssociationProxy?
I have a pretty standard association table
class GroupUserAssociation(Base):
    __tablename__ = "group_user_associations"
    group_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("groups.id"), primary_key=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True)

    group: Mapped["Group"] = relationship(back_populates="user_associations")
    user: Mapped["User"] = relationship(back_populates="group_associations")

    membership_state: Mapped[GroupMembershipState] # A str Enum

And the "Left" table in my case:

class Group(BaseEntity):
    __tablename__ = "groups"
    
    ...

    user_associations: Mapped[List["GroupUserAssociation"]] = relationship(
        "GroupUserAssociation",
        back_populates="group",
    )

    # I want a users proxy with the shape {"user": association.user, "membership_state": association.membership_state"}
    users: AssociationProxy = association_proxy(
         ...some magic here...
    )

How do I get the users field to be in the shape that I want?
I was looking at proxy_factory param in association_proxy but its documentation isn't great and I can't figure out how to use it.

The way to think about this is that AssociationProxy can "forward" some field/property from the Association table to the model where you are adding the association_proxy. The "custom" field that we want here is not present directly on the Association table, so we just create it.
class GroupUserAssociation(Base):
    ...

    @property
    user_and_membership_info(self):
        return {"user": association.user, "membership_state": association.membership_state"}

and in the Group model:
class Group(BaseEntity):
    ...

    users: AssociationProxy = association_proxy(
        "user_associations",
        "user_and_membership_info"
    )

